# sudoで$PATHを引き継ぎつつsbinなどをPATHに加えるには？

Tags: linux, sudo

`sudo`したとき、`secure_path`が設定されていてもユーザ固有の`$PATH`を引き継ぐ方法として、
`/etc/sudoers`に

```
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults exempt_groups=developers
```

のように記述する方法が一般的なようです。
しかしこれだとユーザ固有の`$PATH`がそっくりそのまま新しい`$PATH`となってしまいます。
ユーザ固有の`$PATH`と`secure_path`との和集合をsudo時の`$PATH`にしたいのですが、そういうことはできるでしょうか？

Comment: `env_keep = "PATH"` とすればユーザ固有の `$PATH` が引き継がれるのですが、和集合となると難しいですね…

Answer (score 1):

`-i [command]` オプションで .profile や .login を読み込むといいと思います。

次の例では `hoge`ユーザの`.bash_profile` で `~/bin` を追加してます。

user `hoge`:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
#.bash_profile
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

$ cat <<eof > /home/hoge/test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo PATH=$PATH
eof

$ chmod +x /home/hoge/test.sh
```

user `foo`:

```
$ sudo -u hoge /home/hoge/test.sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

$ sudo -i -u hoge /home/hoge/test.sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/hoge/bin
```

ただし、HOME SHELL USER LOGNAME などの環境変数も書き換わりますので ご注意ください。
詳しくは `man sudo`